# uninstall nugetpackage datatables

Tags: nuget, uninstallation, nuget-package

I installed jquery.datatables package but something got wrong. So i wanted to uninstall it and try to install it again. In nuget manager there is now way to uninstall it? The usuall button isn't there as for the other packages. So i tried to uninstall the package using the console:

uninstall-package jquery.datatables

It says install completed but when i try to install it again it says that its already there.

How can i completly remove it?

Is there something i can type in the console or can i restart or unistall the nuget manager in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that NuGet left the package in your packages directory. You could try manually removing the NuGet package.

1. Remove the jquery.datatables from the packages.config file.
2. Remove the packages\jquery.datatables.1.9.4 directory and any files it contains.
3. Remove any files the jquery.datatables NuGet package added to your project.

You could also try the -reinstall option that is available with the Update-Package command:

```
 Update-Package –reinstall <packageName>
```